# ckeditor, php, image display issue

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have a download.php file to display images on a web page as well as downloading files like pdfs, docs, etc.

in ckeditor if the src for the image is /download.php it dispalys like there is no image or broken link image, if the src for the image is http://www.mydomain.com/download.php my image displays just fine in ckeditor.

Any thoughts? And no i cant just make it put the full domain. There is a reason to long, complicated, and stupid to explain thanks to the web hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration you need to set the [`baseHref`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.baseHref) to the full path, then it will add that to the images/files you upload and insert.

Comment: what file is the configuration file? config.js? Also what do i put as the base href?  http://www.mydomain.com/ ?